# SQL what is the query to get all tuples that are updated today (date provided in CollectionDate column in format DD-MMM-YY)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a look of table

```
ID             MSG_TYPE       CollectionDate
515587         GenOut         21-FEB-19 04.09.57.325772000 PM
515588         GenOut         18-JUL-19 01.06.15.307068000 PM
515589         GenOut         22-AUG-18 03.20.15.307069290 PM
515590         GenOut         18-JUL-19 12.03.09.873288000 PM
```

Expected result

```
ID             MSG_TYPE       CollectionDate
515588         GenOut         18-JUL-19 01.06.15.307068000 PM
515590         GenOut         18-JUL-19 12.03.09.873288000 PM
```

Comment: It will be useful to list the exact type of the `CollectionDate` column from the table DDL script.

Answer (score 1):

A `where` clause seems sufficient.  You should really fix your column so it is stored as a *bona fide* date, not a string.

That said, you can use:

```
where collectiondate like concat(date_format(curdate(), '%d-%b-%y'), '%')
```

Or:

```
where str_to_date(left(collectiondate, 9), '%d-%b-%y') = curdate()
```

Comment: I can't change the schema of table.